# SWT resizeble layout

Tags: java, layout, swt, desktop

There is any resizeable layout on SWT?

If I want to build a windows with two components. The first component will have a minimum size, but the user should be able to change the width by selecting the "border".

There is any SWT layout for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be using a [`SashForm`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FSashForm.html). [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SashFormExample.htm) is an example and this is what it looks like:

[image]